# Accessing base class variable (of same name)in derived class

Tags: apex

(This is only for academic purpose.Not necessarily a real time scenario)
How do i access base class variable in a derived class.

Say my base class is

```
public virtual class Baseclass
{
public integer a;
}
```

derived class is

```
public class derived extends baseclass{
public integer a;//if i remove this and assign a below.it will obviously point to the only variable which is of baseclass

public void displayname()
{
a = 13;//This implicitily reads as this.a.How do i assign 13 to baseclass variable a here.if i say super a.it gives a compile error
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to define `integer a;` in the derived class as well? If you remove that from the derived class then it will do what you want.

Comment: Its for academic purpose.Not necessarily a real time scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class derived extends baseclass{
public integer a; //if i remove this and assign a below.it will obviously point to the only variable which is of baseclass

 public void displayname(){
     ((Baseclass) this).a = 13;//This implicitily reads as this.a.How do i assign 13 to baseclass variable a here.if i say super a.it gives a compile error
 }

}
```

try the above and this is typically called as variable overshadowing in Java .Hope this helps

Comment: Is this the only way to access baseclass variable(if there is a duplicate name in derived)?

Comment: Yes it working for me

Comment: @sfdc99999 You can access the instance of class and then assign value to a variable as well .

Comment: more specifically it is overriding in java. ONE OF THE CONCEPT THAT SUPPORTS POLYMORPHISM IN APEX.

Comment: instead u can directly access the variable using SUPER keyword. This available in apex but limited to methods and constructors. too. like  instead of this  ((Baseclass) this).a = 13  ----> super.<method name>(param) . this method ofbase class will update the paramaeter.